# Email results.txt file from java jar running on cronjob

Tags: java, unix

I have a java jar that runs on a cronjob that outputs a results-{date}.txt file into a directory and does not email the contents of that file.  Is there a way that I can tell the cronjob to email that file once the jar has finished running?

Or is there a way that I can set an echo to email the latest file in a directory?

Ive also tried to get my java jar to only print results.txt name without the date but cant figure out how to do that.  If this can be done, the first solution would not be needed.

```
private static PrintStream makeOutputStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filename = "results.txt";
    return new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, ParseException, InterruptedException {
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("o", false, "Write output to stdout. By default, output is written to a file named results-[date-time].txt.");
    options.addOption("s", true, "Use the given url as a base for the product page url. Default is " + SHOP_BASE_URL_DEFAULT);
    CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);

    Checker checker = new Checker(cmd.getOptionValue("s", BASE_URL_DEFAULT));

     PrintStream stream = System.out;
     if (cmd.hasOption("o")) {
         stream = makeOutputStream();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create script in bash and add that to crontab in that script run:

1. your java program
2. mail sending command example 'mail -s "$(echo -e "title\nContent-Type: text/html")" $MAILING_LIST < report_$CUR_DATE*'

Comment: Thanks, I got it working.  Im just going to use results-* and remove each one after i have cat the file